# What are the options or ways to pass variables to another url when user click on the link?

Tags: javascript, php, url, parameter-passing

I have two ways to do it but I'm still weighing the options.

1st option : Using GET method to retrieve variables from the url.

2nd option : Using GET to retrieve  the variables and post it to the url so that variables will be hidden.

```
<a href="mysurvey_status.php --$variable--"> Status Summary</a>
```

I need this variable to execute my PHP function to display my table on the other page.

Comment: If the variables are gonna be in the `href` any way, what point would there be in redirecting to a `POST`? Just use a normal url with parameters.

Comment: Putting data in the request body instead of the query string won't hide it (browser developer tools make it trivial to inspect requests). Any time you think about switching to POST for that reason: *stop*.

Comment: Why do the variables need to be hidden? If your answer is "security" then stop, it won't work.

Comment: @GordonM I do not want others to manipulate the data on the url. Yeah, it is due to security.

Comment: Can you suggest any ways to do that properly?

Comment: No, you can't hide no variable from experienced user. There are many tools to reveal hidden inputs.

Comment: security by obscurity... yeah that works... not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to hide you variables is to store them on server side and use `session` to pass them between scripts.

POST variables are not hidden at all, there are many ways to reveal them.